# which of the following satement is true? ..

Tags: real-analysis

let $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ = { f : $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ | f is continious  and there  exist  a  compact  set $K$ such that  $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in K ^c$} . let $g(x) = e^{-x^2}$  for all $x \in$ $\mathbb{R}.$

which of the  following satemnet is true?

1.There  exist a sequence {$f_n$} in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly

2.There exist a sequemce  {$f_n$} in $C_c (\mathbb{R})$ such that $f_n \rightarrow g$ pointwise

3. If  a sequence in $C_c (\mathbb{R})$ converge pointwise to g then it must converge uniformly to $g$.

4.There doesnot  exists any sequence $C_c (\mathbb{R})$ converging pointwise to $g$

My attempts :  I thinks  option 1 and option 3  Trues...I don't  know  how to Prove  But  in my  mind i was thinking  that  uniform convergence implies  Pointwise convergence,,,,

Any solution/Hints  will be  appreciated

Thanks in advance,,i would be thanksful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. True: Let 
   $$f_n(x):=\varphi_n(x)e^{-x^2}$$ where $\varphi_n \in
       C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R};[0,1])$ are cut-off functions such that $\varphi_n=1$ in $|x|\leq n$ and $\varphi_n=0$ in $|x|\geq n+1$.
2. True, this follows from 1).
3. False. Start from $f_n$ but add a function $\psi_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\operatorname{supp}\psi_n\subset [n+1,n+2]$, and such that $\psi_n(\xi)=-1$ for some $\xi\in (n+1,n+2)$. Then $g_n:=f_n+\psi_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $g_n(x)\to e^{-x^2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, but $g_n$ does not converge uniformly to $e^{-x^2}$ because 
   $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|g_n(x)-e^{-x^2}|\geq |g_n(\xi)-e^{-\xi^2}|\geq 1  $$
4. Clearly false.

EDIT: I used $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})=C_c(\mathbb{R})\cap C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ because I could but if you replace it with $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ everything remains true (since $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\subset C_c(\mathbb{R})$).

Comment: thanks  u @ lorenz0

Comment: Can you please elaborate the option 3?@Lorenzo Quarsia

Comment: Can you please elaborate option  3?@stupid

Comment: Why you needed $ \ C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$?@Lorenzo Quarsia

Comment: @cmi see my edit, if you replace $C_c^{\infty}$ with $C_c$ everything remains true. What do you not understand about my answer? It seems clear to me.